# Extracting points from a matrix tangential to a centreline

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying to solve the following problem preferably using MATLAB:

I have a tube with two branches (please see attached in the link below the point cloud showing this model where the columns are x y z and a variable respectively). I also have a centreline that runs through the main branch of the model. Please also see attached to the link the centreline points where the columns are x y z respectively . I have also attached images showing the model [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppk5S.jpg) and centreline [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRKMv.png). The red outline drawn on the model geometry highlights where the main branch is located.

At each centreline point I am trying to extract the points located tangentially along the model to that centreline point to a new matrix along with their corresponding variable value. I have attached two images [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwRzY.png) that hopefully clarify better what I want to achieve [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBTr7.png).

https://drive.google.com/file/d/14JPx_9zKFjbLYA_WZ4Dj4m4Svvoip6Ju/view?usp=sharing